# How can the size of Shiny Standalone Application be reduced?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Standalone Shiny Application made using the framework [Desktop Deploy R](https://github.com/wleepang/DesktopDeployR)

The size of the app is now 380 mb and I want to  reduce its size. Is there any way to solve this problem or should I use different framework or package?

```
    Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
    ----                 -------------         ------ ----
    d-----          8/3/2023   5:41 PM                app
    d-----          8/3/2023   5:41 PM                dist
    -a----         7/27/2023   3:53 PM             39 .gitignore
    -a----         7/27/2023   3:53 PM          11558 LICENSE
    -a----         7/27/2023   3:53 PM             31 MyApp.bat
    -a----         7/27/2023   3:53 PM           7952 README.md
    
    
    PS C:\Users\myr\Desktop\MyApp> ls app
    
    
        Directory: C:\Users\myr\Desktop\MyApp\app
    
    
    Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
    ----                 -------------         ------ ----
    d-----          8/3/2023   5:41 PM                library
    d-----          8/3/2023   5:41 PM                shiny
    -a----         7/27/2023   3:53 PM             81 app.R
    -a----         7/30/2023  11:26 AM           1531 config.cfg
    -a----          8/3/2023  10:32 AM            475 packages.txt


PS C:\Users\myr\Desktop\MyApp> ls dist


    Directory: C:\Users\myr\Desktop\MyApp\dist


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----          8/3/2023   5:41 PM                R-Portable
d-----          8/3/2023   5:41 PM                script
-a----         7/27/2023   3:53 PM           2468 USAGE.md
```

Here the library takes the most space about 200mb

Packages used:

```
askpass, backports, base64enc, bit, bit64, blob, broom, bslib, bsplus, cachem, callr, cellranger, cli, clipr, colorspace, commonmark, conflicted, cpp11, crayon, crosstalk, curl, data.table, DBI, dbplyr, digest, dplyr, DT, dtplyr, ellipsis, evaluate, fansi, farver, fastmap, fontawesome, forcats, fs, gargle, generics, ggplot2, glue, googledrive, googlesheets4, gt, gtable, haven, highr, hms, htmltools, htmlwidgets, httpuv, httr, ids, isoband, jquerylib, jsonlite, knitr, labeling, later, lazyeval, lifecycle, lubridate, magrittr, memoise, mime, modelr, munsell, openssl, pillar, pkgconfig, plotly, prettyunits, processx, progress, promises, ps, purrr, R6, ragg, rappdirs, RColorBrewer, Rcpp, readr, readxl, rematch, rematch2, reprex, rlang, rmarkdown, rstudioapi, rvest, sass, scales, selectr, shiny, shinyalert, shinycssloaders, shinyjs, shinypop, sourcetools, stringi, stringr, sys, systemfonts, textshaping, tibble, tidyr, tidyselect, tidyverse, timechange, tinytex, tzdb, utf8, uuid, vctrs, viridisLite, vroom, withr, writexl, xfun, xml2, xtable, yaml
```

Packages used in Shiny Application:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(writexl)
library(data.table)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(bsplus)
library(DT)
library(shinyalert)
```

Comment: Not sure. First, on my win11 machine at least, the R-4.2.3 installation directory is over 176M, so 380M sounds a _lot_ over that, but ... Second, I'm not intimately familiar with that mechanism (though I know of it), so it's likely that it adds something, but whether it's 1K or 100M, I don't know. Third, what are you packaging with your app? Does it include data files? Images? Anything else? There's literally no way to know without seeing what you've created.

Comment: Personally, I tend to wait at least an hour after a question is posted before closing it for "needs details", so I'm not going to vote-to-close, but there are already two votes and not everybody holds off (even an hour seems quick). I suggest you [edit] your question and add more context so that we can at least guess a bit more. Good luck!

Comment: @r2evans Is the info enough?

Comment: Better, yes, thank you. What packages are you using? (What is in `./app/library/`?)

Comment: Added packages found in the library and also in the Shiny App

Comment: `tidyverse` is rather large, have you looked at the size of the subdirectories in the `library`?

Comment: tidyverse here is showing only 600kb. While look at the dir, plotly took the most storage of 7mb

Comment: For some tangible examples, on my win11 machine, `shiny` is 10MB alone, `dplyr` and `readxl` each take up 2.5-3M, `data.table` almost 5M, `plotly` almost 7M, etc. While I don't think any one package is larger than `shiny` in what you've shown, especially when installing a meta-package like `tidyverse` (that installs a LOT of other packages), it's papercuts.

Comment: For context, `tidyverse` adds almost zero capability, it just adds convenience, so that 600K is relatively a waste of space. If you want to reduce size, first: don't install `tidyverse`, find the packages you _need_ and install them. From there, if you're using a large package for convenience, then you might want to check for other ways to do what they do, perhaps in base R or another package you must have.

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice. There's also library folder inside R portable with less packages. Are those necessary too?

Comment: Typically those are base packages ... remove at your own peril. While I'm confident you should be able to remove _some_ of them, I don't know which, and they are included in base R for a reason ... something somewhere relies on them always being available. For instance, you might be able to remove `MASS` if you aren't using its functions, but obviously base packages such as `stats`, `utils`, `tools`, `graphics`, `grDevices`, `grid`, etc, should not be touched.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254784/discussion-between-golem-and-r2evans).